# ELB Instance Internal IP disclosure

Tags: nginx, security, ip, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

There is a vulnerability detected by Nessus that involves [Internal IP Disclosure](https://www.tenable.com/pvs-plugins/4666) in the Elastic Beanstalk servers with Nginx and Phusion Passenger at the response headers, in the `Location` header.

I already tried setting in the configuration:

```
server_name_in_redirect on;
```

Also tried...

```
return 301 $scheme://www.website.com$request_uri;
```

in the Nginx configuration but it doesn't seem to work. By setting both configurations in the Passenger and Nginx configuration files.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Create a default virtualhost that doesn't redirect, and instead displays a 404 to folks accessing via just the IP.